# Passwordless authentication not working

Tags: ssh, unix, sftp, sshd

I am trying to setup a passwordless authentication between my webserver & a reporting server using the below steps. It works fine in my dev environment , however in the customer environment it doesn't.

---

Steps :

As testUser user on web server :

```
mkdir ~/.ssh

cd ~/.ssh

ssh-keygen (use default file location and empty passphrase)

ssh-keygen -t dsa (as before)
```

Transfer the generated public keys to Reporting server.

As testUser user -

```
sftp testUser@<ReportServerName>

put id_dsa.pub

put id_rsa.pub

quit
```

Do the following steps on the Reporting server.

As testUser user

```
mkdir ~/.ssh

cd ~/.ssh

cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

cat ~/id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2

rm ~/id_*.pub

chmod 644 auth*
```

As root user
    vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Uncomment ‘PubkeyAuthentication yes’

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

---

After doing these steps when I try to a sftp testUser@ it still asks me for a password.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Why are you putting one key in `authorized_keys` and the other in `authorized_keys2`? (The latter name has been abandoned many years ago.) Why do you have two keys in the first place? (Just one type is enough, usually rsa or ed25519.)

Comment: it should be `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Also what openssh version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possible pitfalls here. Because you created the directories yourself, permissions may be wrong.

The following permissions are **required**:

- The `~/.ssh` directory should not be readable by anyone but the owner, so usually `chmod 700`. It **must not** be *writable* by anyone but the owner.
- Private key files **must not** be *readable or writable* by anyone but the owner, so usually `chmod 600`. `ssh-keygen` already does that for you.
- The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file **must not** be *writable* by anyone but the owner, so at least `chmod 644`. (Public keys are not secret—per definition!)

If in doubt: Run `sshd` in debug mode. It will stay attached to the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/bin/sshd -p 2222 -d
```

Then, connect from your client, on port 2222:

```
ssh -p 2222 my-ssh-server
```

The server will log whatever error it encounters. It could be something likes this:

> Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/fuzzy/.ssh

Comment: Really helpful about running in debug mode. From that I quickly realized that not only .ssh, but the directory containing .ssh has to be chmod 700. None of the many instructions I read mentioned that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of debug steps:

- Check the logs on both sides.  Likely `/var/log/auth.log`.
- Run your ssh connection in verbose mode `ssh -v`.
- Check access of the each directory from `~/.ssh` to '/'. None of these directories can be or other writable.

You can test access with these two lines. (Assumes root permissions are OK).

```
cd ~/.ssh; DIR=$PWD
while [ $DIR != '/' ]; do ls -ld $DIR; DIR=$(dirname $DIR); done
```